# Create new database in PhpStorm

Tags: database, phpstorm

I have a mysql database on localhost. Now I want to install some web application which needs an empty database (for example "myapplication").

How can I create such database in PhpStorm 9?

Comment: This might depend on the database system you use. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase  I've seen I'd missed to note the type of Database. I've added it now. 
But at least I found that phpstorms mysql-plugin don't have a simple way to do it by a UI. You have to use manual way via create DB. (see my following comment)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I only found the way to open the SQL-Console (CTRL+SHIFT+F10), and create in manually by entering SQL command:

CREATE DATABASE myapplication;

Ok, is not much to write, so maybe no need to have a GUI for that ?! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have mysql installed on your system type `mysql` in the phpstorm terminal and then hit ENTER

you should now see `mysql>`

now type `create database my_database_name;` (including the semicolon at the end) and hit ENTER

that will create a new database called `my_database_name`

now you can just type `exit` and press ENTER to get out of the mysql console